# Конфликт метаклассов при наследовании класса из другого файла

Tags: python-3.x, веб-программирование, django

При изучении django 2 возникла данная проблема. Я пытаюсь наследовать класс CategoryListMixin, который находится в директории отличной от класса, который его наследует и получаю ошибку: "*TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases*"

код файла views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from generic.mixins import CategoryListMixin


class MainPageView(TemplateView, CategoryListMixin):
    template_name = 'mainpage.html'
```

код файла CategoryListMixin:

```
from django.views.generic.base import ContextMixin


class CategoryListMixin(ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_url'] = self.request.path
        return context
```

Однако, если поместить эти классы в один файл (views.py) следующим образом:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.base import ContextMixin


class CategoryListMixin(ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_url'] = self.request.path
        return context

class MainPageView(TemplateView, CategoryListMixin):
    template_name = 'mainpage.html'
```

То ошибка исчезает и всё отрабатывает, как должно. Решения типа: [Multiple inheritance metaclass conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720217/multiple-inheritance-metaclass-conflict)
 не помогают.
В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел решение проблемы. Дело в том, что импортируя класс "CategoryListMixin" я импортировал весь файл с таким же названием, в котором собственно и был описан данный класс. Далее я пытался наследовать весь файл вместо класса и получал описанную ошибку

Собственно ошибка была в данной строке:

```
from generic.mixins import CategoryListMixin
```

Верный импорт необходимого мне класса:

```
from generic.mixins.CategoryListMixin import CategoryListMixin
```

После данного исправления всё заработало.